# Network video rendering

Tags: software-recommendation

So I have a weak tablet with Windows 10 on it and a useless PC with alright specs without monitor, mouse and keyboard which I want to turn into a server in order to remotely edit and render videos on it from my Windows 10 tablet.

I discovered that network video rendering is hard to set up in latest versions of Adobe Premiere Pro or Sony Vegas Pro (which even doesnt have such option in latest versions). So I thought I could run normal desktop windows 10 on this PC and connect to it via remote desktop application which can be found in store but i doubt that it will work because the PC doesnt have monitor, keyboard and mouse, so it will be impossible even to log in the user at the startup.

OS doesnt matter as long as I will be able to remotely edit and render videos on the server from my Win10 tablet so I am just asking for an editing software that can be used the way I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Google the config setup to have the computer auto-login, bypassing the login screen. You can change a setting in regedit and it will auto login to the default profile, which cannot use a password.

Over Remote Desktop, you can then control the system.

If it crashes, you'll have to do a hard reboot.

Answer (score 0):

As a second option which I played with and it did work (to a point);

Is you can setup an Amazon AWS account:

Build a Workstation Render System; install all of your software; plugins;  etc. You can do your build on a simple 4 or 8 core machine; with a 2nd attached SSD drive.

Then create images of your system, and delete the system.

When you need to do major renders; or fast; you can deploy as many systems / at whatever spec setup you want (cores/ram/etc).

You'll be prompted for Adobe Serials if you're using core applications; but this is a great way to quickly and cost effectively launch 10 48 core systems in an hour or two; while uploading your trimmed project; which can all be accessed from your guest systems, and render the video in sections with tails of a few frames to piece together back on your host side.

Answer (score 0):

Pick up a used server host on EBay for about $500.00 with 2 x 3GHz I5 8 core Hyperthreaded CPU's (equivalent to 32 3 GHz cores) and 128 GB RAM.  Load it up with Windows and watch the lights dim as you start rendering.

Caution: wear ear plugs. They're built for speed and reliability, but sound like jet engines.